# Calcular ancho de banda para 100BaseTx y 802.11n

Tags: networking

Si una red dispone un acceso a Internet de 10 Mbps de bajada y 1 Mbps de subida. La red interna ofrece dos modos de acceso: 100Base-TX y WiFi 802.11n. ¿Qué modo de acceso ofrece un mayor ancho de banda?

¿Qué cálculos me llevarían a discriminar entre los dos modos de acceso?

Answer (score 1):

Te añado datos que ayudaran a entender los dos métodos y un marco teorico para que puedas decidir: disponibilidad del medio, máximo teórico, estabilidad, precio,mantenimiento y escalabilidad.

### [802.11n](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n)

- Se trata del conocido `WIFI`.
- Es un [medio no guiado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medio_de_transmisi%C3%B3n#Medios_de_transmisi%C3%B3n_no_guiados), por radiofrecuencia. Al Ser no guiado no se puede asegurar que el canal de intercambio este disponible el 100% del tiempo.
- Alta probabilidad de que existan escenarios/ acontecimientos de mediana estabilidad.
- Máximo teórico de 600Mbps.
- Bajo coste de implementación. Bajo coste mantenimiento.
- Poca escalabilidad.

### [100BaseTx](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/100Base-TX)

- Se trata del conocido `RJ45`.
- Es un medio guiado, por el cual si podemos asegurar la disponibilidad del mismo en un entorno típico domestico, empresarial, exterior.
- Muy alta estabilidad.
- Máximo teórico de 100Mbps por canal ( TX / RX ).
- Muy bajo coste de implementación y mantenimiento.
- Buena escalabilidad.

#### red de acceso 10/1

- La tecnología limitante de ancho de banda no va a ser ni el Wifi ni el Cable. Va a ser la red de acceso.
- Hace falta conocer el medio de acceso. Si es XDSL, FTTH, Coaxial...
- Hace falta conocer el uso que se la va a dar, real time (por ejemplo vozip), crítico ( por ejemplo servidor web), backup. El uso va a determinar una tecnología u otra.

#### sobre los cálculos

En tu caso no hay agregaciones de enlaces, ni de consumidores o productores. No hay cálculos que hacer.

Si necesitas conocer cuantos datos vas a consumir de descarga y de subida. Nadas mas que eso.

Tener en cuenta que la red de acceso va a ser el embudo del tránsito.

No existen formulas para conocer la inestabilidad que te dará el wifi.

Puedes hacer pruebas reales, hay programas dedicados a eso. [Iperf](https://iperf.fr/) es uno de los mas conocidos en el caso de que controles los dos extremos. Caso contrario puedes probar directo a internet con [speedtest.net](https://www.speedtest.net/)